# Fixed action on embed src

Tags: php, html, button, embed, mute

I'm using an embedded code on my website, and when the mute button is pressed, I want it to keep muted even when I refresh the page.

For example, every time I mute and then refresh the page, the player starts unmuted. I want it to keep muted even after the refresh.

Is there any way to do this?

```
echo "<EMBED SRC='sounds/down.mp3' WIDTH='200' HEIGHT='100'>";
```

Comment: Set a cookie and check for it when the page reloads.

Comment: could you exemplify, please?

Comment: When the you click `mute` have the JavaScript set a cookie (e.g., player-muted with a value of `true`). When you click play set the cookie value to false. When the page reloads have your JavaScript check for the cookie, and if the cookie's value is `true` your code would mute the player.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand... I've never worked with cookies before. Any code example?

Comment: To set/get cookies check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103596/2518525